# Remove the comma on at the end of every 4th line

Tags: linux, unix, sed

Her is a example of the output. I need to remove the comma at the end of every fourth line.

```
"tester1",
"SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED",
"Thu Mar 19 23:27:57 UTC 2015",
"111.111.11.1"
"tester1",
"SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED",
"Fri Mar 20 00:31:59 UTC 2015",
"111.111.11.1"
```

What I am trying to do is

```
"tester1",
"SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED",
"Thu Mar 19 23:27:57 UTC 2015",
"111.111.11.1"
"tester1",
"SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED",
"Fri Mar 20 00:31:59 UTC 2015",
"111.111.11.1"
```

Comment: Your 4th lines don't have commas

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '4~4 s/,$//' filename
```

I have to point out, though, that in your example output there's no comma at the end of every fourth line.

This should work for you, since the question is tagged "linux" and Linux very nearly always comes with GNU sed. For the sake of completeness: with BSD sed (as found on Mac OS X and *BSD), the `4~4` pattern does not work (it is a GNU extension). There you could do something like

```
sed 'n;n;n;s/,$//' filename
```

...which fetches and prints three extra lines every time and removes the comma at the end of the fourth (unless the end of the input was reached before a fourth line could be fetched).

Alternatively, with awk you could use

```
awk 'NR % 4 == 0 { sub(/,$/, "") } 1' filename
```